# Is adding color: #333333; to the body tag a correct way to change the default color of all text elements?

Tags: html, css

Imagine that I've been creating a website for 2-3 weeks now and suddenly I decide that I don't like the default black color of all text elements which don't have any CSS applied to them and that I want to change their color to something like `#333333` which is a less black black.

Is adding color: #333333; to the body tag the correct way to do it? Could that have any negative effects on other elements that I have custom styling?

Comment: It is working but that doesn't necessarily mean it's the correct way. This is why I am asking this question. I don't want to realize later on that I've made a poor choice which could cause more problems.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way and has been so from day one. That's exactly how CSS is designed to solve these kind of problems. But I do not recommend using inline styling (`<body style="..." ...>`).

Answer (score 1):

CSS prioritises the code lower down, for example, this:

```
<style>
  p {
    color: blue;
  }
  p { 
    color: green;
  }
</style>
<p>Hello</p>
```

Would result in the `color` of the paragraph element becoming green.

So to answer your question, anything above your CSS properties for body would be overridden.

Also, `id` and `class` attributes take priority over position, so if you wanted to give the elements that you don't want to get changed a class and keep it as black that would work also.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll have any negative affects on any elements, however i would just reference the tags specifically to be sure like

```
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: #333333
}
```

But like the comment, give it a try and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

This is enough, as it allows for the color to be 'passed down' through the cascade. Place this at the **start** of your stylesheet:

```
body {
    color: #333;
}
```

Avoid using inline styles:

```
<body style="color: #333"> <!-- Don't to this -->
```

Inline styles have a different specificity than CSS selectors, and it's a whole chapter in itself. 
 Plus, it's easier to separate concerns and have you layout separate from your stylesheets.
 And have everything grouped together within your styles.

Answer (score -2):

The most simple way to do so is by CSS the following way:

```
* {
   color: #333333;
}
```

Changing color in HTML with the style attribute is actually never the best practice.

Comment: You have to avoid the `*` selector in CSS. It will change the background color of other elements too.

Comment: Simply adding it on the body would suffice. The cascade has it's purpose. By doing this, it would cancel the inheritance of all elements, even if the color would be changed on an intermediary element further on. Don't do this.